# AngularJS : twice stateChangeStart and no stateChangeSuccess

Tags: angularjs

I tried to develop a simple code to manage user roles. Some parts of my back-office are not allowed for guest but allowed for admin and I've got a problem with "stateChangeStart" in run function.

1. login into the back-office
2. redirect to /dashboard (in chrome console : "stateChangeStart", "stateChangeSuccess")
3. user clicks on "user management" link but he is not allowed to see the content so he is redirected to /forbidden (in chrome console : "stateChangeStart", "stateChangeSuccess")
4. **user clicks again** on "user management" but same as 3. he can't see the content **BUT in chrome console : "stateChangeStart", "stateChangeStart"**

Do you have an idea of the problem ?

Here my code :

**my run.js :**

```
var stateChangeStartEvent = $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function ()
        {
            console.log("ok start event");
            $rootScope.loadingProgress = true;
        });

        // De-activate loading indicator
        var stateChangeSuccessEvent = $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function ()
        {
            console.log("ok change event");
            $timeout(function ()
            {
                $rootScope.loadingProgress = false;
            });
        });

        // Store state in the root scope for easy access
        $rootScope.state = $state;

        // Cleanup
        $rootScope.$on('$destroy', function ()
        {
            stateChangeStartEvent();
            stateChangeSuccessEvent();
        });

        $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams)
        {
            var authorizedRoles = toState.roles.authorized;

            if (toState.authenticate)
            {
                var isAuthorized = authService.isAuthorized(authorizedRoles);
                var isAuthenticated = authService.isAuthenticated();

                if (!isAuthorized) {
                    event.preventDefault(); 
                    if (!isAuthenticated)
                    {
                        $rootScope.$broadcast('auth.not_authenticated');
                        $state.transitionTo('app.auth_login');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $rootScope.$broadcast('auth.not_authorized');  
                        $state.transitionTo('app.auth_forbidden');
                    }
                    return;
                }

            }
        });
```

**isAuthorized function :**

```
 function isAuthorized(authorizedRoles)
        {

            ... // get my current user and data here

            if (!angular.isArray(authorizedRoles)) {
                authorizedRoles = [authorizedRoles];
            }

            var isAllAuthorized = authorizedRoles.indexOf("all");

            if (isAllAuthorized !== -1)
                return true;


            var isUserAuthorized = authorizedRoles.indexOf(currentUser.role);
            if (isUserAuthorized == '-1')
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
```

**user-management module :**

```
(function ()
{
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.users-management', [])
        .config(config);

function config($stateProvider, msNavigationServiceProvider, USER_ROLES)
    {
        // State
        $stateProvider.state('app.users_management', {
            url      : '/users',
            views    : {
                'content@app': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/main/users-management/users-management.html',
                    controller : 'UsersManagementController as vm'
                }
            }
            roles : {
                authorized: [USER_ROLES.admin]
            },
            authenticate: true
        });
  }

  })();
```

Thank you very much !

edit :

I think get "StateChangeStart" twice times it's normal. I had a console log in StateChangeStart event (console.log(toState.name)) and I can see this at step 2 :

- stateChangeStart // event
- app.users_management // try to access to this page but the user hasn't good role
- stateChangeStart // state.transitionTo('app.auth_forbidden')
- app.auth_forbidden // try to access to this page. User can access to it
- stateChangeSuccess // stateChangeSuccess is launched

I'm ok with that, it works like I want but at step 3 (user clicks again on the same link but he doesn't access and he is already on the forbidden page) :

- stateChangeStart event
- app.users_management // try to access but he can't. He sould be redirected to forbidden page but he is already on this page...

no StateChangeSuccess event launched...

Comment: you are not follw angular best practices.

Comment: If you have an example to do it in a better way, I take it because I'm a beginner with Angularjs :)

Comment: best example you search at john papa's documents

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but I don't know if it's really good way. Anyway: I launch an event and catch this event :

in run.js

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams)
{
    var authorizedRoles = toState.roles.authorized;

    if (toState.authenticate)
    {
        var isAuthorized = authService.isAuthorized(authorizedRoles);
        var isAuthenticated = authService.isAuthenticated();

        if (!isAuthorized) {

            if (!isAuthenticated)
            {
                event.preventDefault(); 
                $rootScope.$broadcast('auth.not_authenticated');
                $state.go('app.auth_login');
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                event.preventDefault(); 
                $rootScope.$broadcast('auth.not_authorized');   // launch event
                $state.go('app.auth_forbidden');
                return;
            }
        }
    }

 }
```

and catch the event :

```
$rootScope.$on('auth.not_authorized', function (event) {
            // some code here
        });
```

It works but I really think there is a better way to do that.